# How add Angular Highcharts to my angular project?

Tags: angular, highcharts

I do

```
npm install highcharts-angular --save
npm install highcharts --save
```

and I add this to app.module.ts

```
import { HighchartsChartModule } from 'highcharts-angular';
```

and

```
@NgModule({
imports: [
...
HighchartsChartModule
```

and I add this to my component.ts:

```
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
Highcharts: typeof Highcharts = Highcharts;
chartOptions: Highcharts.Options = {
series: [
  {
    type: 'line',
    pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
    data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
  }
]
```

};

and in the HTML file I add this

```
<highcharts-chart [Highcharts]="Highcharts" [options]="chartOptions" style="width: 100%; height:400px; display: block;"></highcharts-chart>
```

but nothing appeared

Answer (score 0):

Could you follow below link. It's working fine from my side

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hsodq9

Comment: Exactly, it should work like this. Mohsni, do you get any errors/warnings?